# how can i use django form dropdown to my template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

i've created a form that has fields with dropdown, one for Countries and another one for Nationality
but i do not know how to pass it to my html template.
How can I solve this problem? 
i wrote my models and passed it to my form.py and use it into my template

Models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    E_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    COUNTRY_CHOICES = [('saudi arabia +966','SAUDI ARABIA +966'),
                       ('oman +968','OMAN +968'),
                       ('kuwait +965','KWUAIT +965'),
                       ('Qatar +948','QATAR +948')]
    country = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES, null=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    phone_code = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    NATIONALITY_CHOICES = [('خليجي','خليجي'),
                           ('ليس خليجي','ليس خليجي')]
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=NATIONALITY_CHOICES, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

forms.py

```
    from django import forms
    from .models import User

    class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('first_name', 'second_name', 'E_mail', 'country', 'phone', 'phone_code','birthday', 'nationality',)
```

form_page.html

```
    <form action="{% url 'LandingPage:form_page' %}" method="POST" class="ui inverted form container">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="field">
            <label>البريد الألكتروني</label>
            <input type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="joe@schmoe.com" {{form.E_mail}}>
        </div>
        <div class="ui field">
            <label>أختر الدولة</label>
            <select name="gender" class="ui dropdown" id="select" {{form.country}}>
                <option value="">أختر الدولة</option>
                <option value="Saudi">Saudi Arabia +966</option>
                <option value="Qatar">Qatar +974</option>
                <option value="Oman">Oman +968</option>
                <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait +965</option>
                <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain +973</option>

            </select>
        </div>

        <!-- Mobile Number -->
        <div class="ui field">
            <label>رقم الهاتف</label>

            <div class="inline fields">
                <div class="eight wide field">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="(xxx)" {{form.phone}}>
                </div>

                <div class="three wide field" {{form.phone_code}}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="الكود">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Nationalety -->
        <div class="ui field">
            <label>الجنسية</label>
            <select name="gender" class="ui dropdown" id="select" {{form.nationality}}>
                <option value="">الجنسية</option>
                <option value="خليجي">خليجي</option>
                <option value="ليس خليجي">ليس خليجي</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button class="ui fluid positive button" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <form action="{% url 'LandingPage:form_page' %}" method="POST" class="ui inverted form container">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="field">
            <label>البريد الألكتروني</label>
            {{form.E_mail}}
        </div>
        <div class="ui field">
            <label>أختر الدولة</label>
            {{form.country}}
        </div>

        <!-- Mobile Number -->
        <div class="ui field">
            <label>رقم الهاتف</label>

            <div class="inline fields">
                <div class="eight wide field">
                    {{form.phone}}
                </div>

                <div class="three wide field">
                    {{form.phone_code}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Nationalety -->
        <div class="ui field">
            <label>الجنسية</label>
            {{form.nationality}}
        </div>
        <button class="ui fluid positive button" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Django template will rendering it for you based on form field. About placeholder or any other html attribute, you could set it on your UserForm to make it appear in the template.

Comment: it works now, you helped me a lot Thank You :)
i will add a placeholder to form and i will try if it worked.